# How to change content of a div on a button click with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a site similar to [this one](https://www.linksys.com/us/design-your-velop/?fbclid=IwAR1-UwC3FSYnhwux9LWWllDsbsyJEtWIRUBe6YMsklH1XmlYfZlt3LJdkQE). I can't figure out how to do the animation stuff, but I know I'm doing something wrong because it doesn't work as intended.

```js
$('#c2').hide();

$('#configbtn').click(function() {
  $('#c1').hide();
  $('#c2').show();
});
```

```css
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="c1" class="container text-center my-auto">
  Lorem ipsum
  <a id="configbtn" class="btn btn-transparent btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">dolor sit amet</a>
</div>
<div id="c2" style="display: none;" class="container text-center my-auto">
  Consectetur 
  <a id="selection1" class="btn btn-transparent btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">adipiscing elit</a>
</div>
```

Comment: try `$('#c1').css("display", "none");` and `$('#c2').css("display", "block");`

Comment: @OmarMneimneh trying it now.

Comment: @OmarMneimneh you seem to be missing the point of 'animation' in the question. `show()` and `hide()` are much better practice anyway, if that is the goal.

Comment: look at `fade()`

Comment: Omar's suggestion works but how do i implement a css variable while being shown/hidden?

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, I think there's a jQuery function called `animate` https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try my code:

JS:

```
$('#configbtn').click(function() { 
   $('#c1').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
     setTimeout(function(){
        $('#c2').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible'); 
     }, 300);  
});
```

Full code with html and css in [here](https://codepen.io/phuongnm153/pen/mdyQmYb)
, you will have the animation as you expect